# find tcp flows using scapy

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I am using scapys sniff function to capture tcp and udp packets.I would like to know the tcp flow and how long the flow existed.in wireshark we have session id which is internal to wireshark.I want to know how long the flow existed using for packet sniffed using scapy.
is any field in tcp or udp packet or any way to calculate how long the flow existed. I am searching for solution in google but no luck with the answer.
We also have a graph in wireshark to see the flow arrows.can we achieve the same using python.

Answer (score 1):

Each packet has a timestamp associated with it, which you can easily retrieve as follows:

```
>>> pkt = Ether() / IP() / UDP()
>>> pkt.time
1411350054.376391
>>>
```

So it's just a matter of find the first TCP packet and the last TCP packet in the session to calculate the duration.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.I have many packets in my capture like 500 packets.i need to calculate tcp flows In the capture.we dont have any thing by default to calculate in scapy.your answer is appreciated.thank you